# How to set the url of Axis2 web service and admin page?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, apache-axis

When you generate an Axis2 web service in Eclipse, the URL of the web service and admin page is also automatically generated in this pattern:

Axis2 admin page: http://ipaddress:port/webApplicationName
Web service endpoint: http://ipaddress:port/webApplicationName/services/serviceName/serviceMethod

Is it possible to customize the generated URL? The reason behind this is I have to bundle the axis2 web service inside another application so they will be sharing one folder. I am that there might be a conflict in their URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just specify the URL in the underlying WSDL?

Have you checked [this](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/BottomUpAxis2WebService/bu_tutorial.html) tutorial?

And is it a requirement to use Axis2? My personal opinion is that it produces very strange code. I would recommend to go with the standard JAX-WS found wihin the Java 6 SDK. Here you may want to consider the tool documentation for [wsimport](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsimport.html) or [wsgen](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsgen.html).